# Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central

Tags: maven, junit, maven-3, artifactory, artifact

I use **Artifactory**.

```
Intranet                           |      Internet
---------------------------------------------------------------------
client <------> Artifactory <------|----> Remote repository: jcenter
```

When I run (after removing the .m2 content related to JUnit)

```
mvn clean package -U
```

on the client, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MyProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:MyProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: **Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central** (http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release) -> [Help 1]

part of the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
Downloaded: http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom (24 KB at 164.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release/com/oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.1/ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.484s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 25 17:19:01 EET 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MyProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:MyProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central (http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

How can I fix this problem?

---

#### Details:

1. The **connection** between Artifactory and the remote repository **works**.

   - tested from Artifactory, using the Test button
   - the other .jar files are brought into .m2/repository (E.g.: log4j-1.2.17.jar)
2. The **junit/junit/4.12** folder is **created** under **.m2/repository**, but it contains only the following files:

   - _maven.repositories
   - junit-4.12.jar.lastUpdated
   - junit-4.12.pom
   - junit-4.12.pom.sha1
3. The **jcenter remote repository** contains JUnit 4.12: http://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/
4. Running

   ```
   mvn clean package -U -X
   ```

   will show the following output

   ```
   ...
   Downloading: http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
   [DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\first.last\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar.lastUpdated
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 1.903s
   [INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 25 17:25:51 EET 2016
   [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/155M
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MyProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:MyProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central (http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release) -> [Help 1]
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project MyProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:MyProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central (http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
   Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:MyProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central (http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release)
           at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
           ... 22 more
   Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central (http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release)
           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
           at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
           ... 23 more
   Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central (http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release)
           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
           ... 24 more
   Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact junit:junit:jar:4.12 in central (http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release)
           at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:947)
           at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
           at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
           at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   [ERROR]
   [ERROR]
   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
   ```
5. If I **upload manually** the **junit-4.12.jar** file in http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/libs-release-local , it **works**, but I'd like to keep that folder only for the files that are not in the official remote repositories (like ojdbc7.jar).
6. The following URL http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar?trace contains:

   ```
   Request ID: ...
   Repo Path ID: libs-release:junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
   Method Name: GET
   User: admin
   Time: 2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00
   Thread: http-nio-8081-exec-346
   Steps: 
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Received request
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Request source = <ip>, Last modified = 01-01-70 01:59:59 +02:00, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-nio-8081-exec-346
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Retrieving info
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Consulting the virtual repo download strategy
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Trying to retrieve resource info from the local storage
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Unable to find resource in libs-release:junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Searching for info in aggregated repositories
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Preparing list of aggregated repositories to search in
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-release'
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-release'
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Appending the virtual repository 'libs-release'
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Appending collective local repositories
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Appending collective local cache repositories
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Appending collective remote repositories
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Intercepting info request with 'MavenMetadataInterceptor'
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Intercepting info request with 'PomInterceptor'
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Processing request as a release resource
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Searching for the resource within libs-release-local
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Unable to find resource in libs-release-local:junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Searching for the resource within ext-release-local
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Unable to find resource in ext-release-local:junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Searching for the resource within jcenter-cache
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Unable to find resource in jcenter-cache:junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Searching for the resource within jcenter
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Returning an unfound resource
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Requested resource is found = false
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Request is HEAD = false
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Request is for a checksum = false
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = true
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Requested resource was not modified = false
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Responding with unfound resource
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Setting default response status to '404' reason to 'Resource not found'
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Response is an instance of UnfoundRepoResourceReason
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Configured to hide un-authorized resources = false
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Original response status is auth related = false
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Using original response status of '404' and message 'Could not find resource'
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Sending error with status 404 and message 'Could not find resource'
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Executing any AfterDownloadErrorAction user plugins that may exist
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Response code wasn't modified by the user plugins
   2016-02-25T18:02:35.664+02:00 Sending response with the status '404' and the message 'Could not find resource'
   ```
7. My **pom.xml** contains:

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <!-- JUnit -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>4.12</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       ...
   </dependencies>
   ```
8. **Software** versions:

   - Artifactory Version 4.5.1
   - Apache Maven 3.0.5

Comment: Can you post the results of http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/libs-release/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar?trace

Comment: It seems that you didn't configure a virtual repository where you can link together your own repository and an external link as maven central. If you don't do this and also didn't include the junit on your repository artifactory will not resolve the dependency. Take a look here [Virtual Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories)

Comment: @Downvoter, what is wrong with my question?

Comment: @engineer probably some hater. There is nothing wrong in my opinion.

Comment: @drorb - added the content at number 6.

Comment: @engineer you added the missing artifact to libs-release-local, so the trace show that the missing library is resolved from there. In order to understand why it is not being resolved from the remote repo you will need to remove the artifact from the local repository and run the trace again

Comment: @drorb , yes, you are right. Sorry. I'll update it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Artifactory have a missed retrieval cached in the jcenter-cache. If Artifactory failed to get junit from JCenter for some reason (for example a timeout) it will cache this failure for the period [configured](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-CacheSettings) in the "Missed Retrieval Cache Period" property of the remote repository.
You can clear this and force Artifactory to try and retrieve the artifact again by [zapping](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-ZappingCaches) the cache.

**Applied for this situation:**

1. Go to Artifacts > Artifact Repository Browser > jcenter-cache > junit/junit > 4.12

   or just click on

   http://my-own-server:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/jcenter-cache/junit/junit/4.12
2. Right click on 4.12 > Zap Cache:

   [image: right click and Zap Cache]